# How do I display a view block next to the branding block in the header?

Tags: views, blocks, 9

I have created a view (*Slideshow*) containing a Flex Slider slideshow I want to display in the free header region right of and next to the branding block. I'm using the Bartik theme; I was disappointed to learn that seemingly blocks in the header always come out above or below each other. (I'd prefer blocks to overlap partially and use the view as a kind of background, but for now that's another cup of tea.)

I've tried to put the view in the Header region, change the weight for *Branding* and *Slideview*, and set them identical, but I cannot achieve it.

Also, I looked for any kind of format/position/size setting for blocks, but this seems to go against Drupal conceptually.

Then I wanted to tweak the block's CSS by adding a float-class similar to this one.

```css
.float-right {
 text-align: right;
 color:rgba(121, 121, 121, 1);
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: italic;
 position: relative;
 top:-10px;
 }
```

I cannot find the file to alter.

What am I missing? Any hint would be highly appreciated. (As you might guess, I'm no Drupal-programmer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's 2022 you really don't want to be using float for layouts - it's hard to control and requires various hacks (like clears) to clean up subsequent element layouts.

If you start off by adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.region-header {
  display: flex;
}
```

You'll see straight away that the branding block and your view appear next to each other.

You can then use align-items, justify-content, gap, etc. to arrange and space the elements as required.

Comment: That worked like a charm – thx! This is very much appreciated 

(I simply cannot cast votes yet.)